# JavaFx observale entity without change the entity itself

Tags: java, javafx, binding

I have a class of entity which have a lot of field and I would like to create observable entity to this class so I can use this to `Binding`.

The entity's code can't be change. how can I do it?

Let's assume that my code look like that:

```
class Car {

   private Wheel wheel;
   private Engine engine;
   private Door door;

   // and a lot of field.

}
```

and I want to create `ObservableCar` that become invalidate each time any of the field change.

> The car code doesn't change. And the class of the field too.

How can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Implement your `Car` class using JavaFX properties:

```
public class Car {

    private final ObjectProperty<Wheel> wheel = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
    public ObjectProperty<Wheel> wheelProperty() {
        return wheel ;
    }
    public final Wheel getWheel() {
        return wheelProperty().get();
    }
    public final void setWhee(Wheel wheel) {
        wheelProperty.set(wheel);
    }

    // other properties...

}
```

Now you can create a `ObjectBinding<Car>` that invalidates when any of the properties invalidate:

```
public class CarBinding extends ObjectBinding<Car> {

    private final Car car ;

    public CarBinding(Car car) {
        this.car = car ;
        bind(car.wheelProperty(), car.engineProperty(), ...);
    }

    @Override
    public Car computeValue() {
        return car ;
    }
}
```

If it's more convenient, you can build the binding directly into your car class:

```
public class Car {

    // properties as before...

    private final ObjectBinding<Car> carBinding = new ObjectBinding<Car>() {
        {
            bind(wheelProperty(), engineProperty(), ...);
        }

        @Override
        public Car computeValue() {
            return Car.this ;
        }
    }

    public ObjectBinding<Car> asBinding() {
        return carBinding ;
    }
}
```

Comment: How does It help? I need to know each time field change.

Comment: Thank you, but the code of car can't be change. The car class remain the same, I think I should create new class for each field and for new class ObserverableCar that bind to the new classes of each field. but I don't know how I should do it, and if it's the good approch to this problem.

Comment: Is `Car` mutable? If so, and it's using just regular fields to represent the data, then there's simply no way to observe when the values of those fields change. Plain old objects just don't have listener notification functionality built into them: you need to use JavaFX properties (or bound bean properties) for that.

Comment: Car is an object that I recived from the net so the object's structure can't be change. The object it's self  isn't mutable.